# Wpf MVVM one ObservableCollection multiple ListViews

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm

in my MainView I added a `UserControl`

```
<TabItem Header="Current Elements">
                <tabData:CurrentElementsControl DataContext="{Binding Path=EditorViewModel.SelectedConfigFile}"></tabData:CurrentElementsControl>
            </TabItem>
```

and set its `DataContext`. The `SelectedConfigFile` got an `ObservableCollection<Elements>` 
where different types of elements are stored.

My `UserControl` is basically a `ListView`

```
<ListView Name="ServiceListView"
                                          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Elements}"                                              
                                          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedElement, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                          Loaded="ServiceListView_Loaded"/>
```

where i want to display items of the `ObservableCollection<Elements>` of a given type.
But I dont want to add another `ObservableCollection` to the `SelectedConfigFile` (The VM) for every type and listview. So I thought I could just set a Filter for my UserControl, using its Loaded event like this (in codebehind):

```
        private void ServiceListView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CollectionView view = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.ServiceListView.ItemsSource);
        view.Filter = ServiceFilter;
    }

        private bool ServiceFilter(object item)
    {           
        if (item is ServiceViewModel ) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

But this will filter the `ObservableCollection<Elements>` aswell, which I need (unfiltered) in other places. Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You obviously need more than 1 view. So don't get the default view which cannot be shared that way. Try creating a new view like this:

```
private void ServiceListView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    CollectionView view = new CollectionView(this.ServiceListView.ItemsSource);
    view.Filter = ServiceFilter;
    //use the created view here such as by assigning it to some ItemsSource
    //...
}
```

Comment: filtering doesnt work now. The Filter Method is called and does its job, but all the elements are displayed in the listview.

Comment: @user3596113 ah of course, we created a new view but that view is currently not used. You have to assign that view to some ListView's `ItemsSource`, I hope you understand the idea.

Comment: i guess its not enough to just set the `ListView` `ItemsSource` like this, is it? `ServiceListView.ItemsSource = view;`

Comment: @user3596113 I understand that you have multiple ListViews here. Just pick which view you want. Are you sure you have multiple ListViews? so where you defined them? I may misunderstand something about your current scenario.

Comment: Yes i got multiple ListViews. For now its just one for the services (`ServiceListView`) but once I can display all the elements of type `ServiceViewModel` in this ListView, I will add another ListView which will display all elements of type `BananaViewModel` (this ViewModel are all stored in the `ObservableCollection<Elements>`.

Comment: @user3596113 do you mean each `Element` has some sub view (which should have the viewmodel of `BananaViewModel`)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63911/discussion-between-user3596113-and-king-king).

Answer (score 0):

Just specifying DataTemplates in the Resources with the respective DataType is enough, e.g.

```
<ListView Name="ServiceListView"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Elements}"                                              
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedElement, Mode=TwoWay}"
          Loaded="ServiceListView_Loaded"/>
    <ListView.Resources>
        <!-- Do NOT set the x:Key -->
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ElementType1}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="Blue"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ElementType2}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Model}" Foreground="Red"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.Resources>
</ListView>
```

If you dont want to display items of a particular type do not define an item template for it. This way the original collection remains untouched, but only certain elements get displayed to the user.